# iOS download SQLite database on application launch

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, download

I'm new at iOS app development, and I'm trying to add some marks to a map (lat,long), using an SQLite database from a web server. This database is growing with new marks every day by users through my website formulary.

What I want is, every time user launches my app, if there is internet, it should check if the remote file (database) is newer, and if so, download it. In case there is no internet connection, the app use the old database.

As I said , I am a beginner. Can someone give me tips, links, or anything that can help me? I have been searching this for 2 days.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is not the correct approach.**

You need to use an **intermediate web server** so have some backend file (PHP, Ruby, etc.) to which you can **send a request** from your iOS app and **receive in response the new entries from the remote database**.

At that point you can **save the data in local in a coreData or in another sqlite db** in your app, and at the next request you will send the **last id downloaded** and again you will receive the new entries.

If you are not an expert, for request and response you can use easily the iOS framework

> AFNetworking 2.0

If you are not an expert of backend interfaces, you can use service like

> parse.com

as database.

Enjoy!

Comment: Perfect, this is the approach! :)